# AngularJS How to enable copy&paste operations on Input element of type="date"?

Tags: angularjs, date, input, copy, paste

I should let the user to copy and paste into `<input type="date"> or <input type="datetime-local">` HTML part:
`<input type="date" id="dateId" ng-model="source.startDate">`.

How can I do so in AngularJS?
Any idea will be highly appreciated..
Thanks!

My temporary solution is -
For Select (in order to Copy), I just added this style to the css file:

```
input.form-control[type="date"],
    input.form-control[type="datetime"],
    input.form-control[type="datetime-local"]
    {
        -webkit-user-select: text;
    }
```

For Paste:
I tried to register each element to 'paste' listener:

`<input type="date" id="dateId" ng-model="source.startDate" ng-init="registerToPasteEventListener('dateId')">`

```
$rootScope.registerToPasteEventListener = function(param) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            const input = document.getElementById(param);
            if(input){
                input.addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
                    if (document.activeElement !== input) {
                        return;
                    }
                    const value = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
                    let datetimeArr = value.split('/');
                    let time = null;
                    if(datetimeArr.length==3) {
                        if(datetimeArr[2].length > 4){
                            //date and time
                            time = datetimeArr[2].slice(6);
                            datetimeArr[2]= datetimeArr[2].slice(0,4)
                        }
                        let dateValue = new Date([datetimeArr[1],datetimeArr[0],datetimeArr[2],time]);    
                        updatedValue = time && document.activeElement.type.includes('datetime') ? dateValue.toJSON().slice(0,16) : dateValue.toJSON().slice(0,10);            
                        $('#'+param).val(updatedValue).trigger('change');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Can paste a date of this format only: dd/mm/yyyy')
                    }
                });    
            }
        },200); 
    }
```

It works, but it's not an elegant solution. I don't want to have a Function inside `setTimeout()`, and all the other strange code there..
Thanks!